# Running same function multiple times with different parameters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I am trying to run the function below to update a very large spreadsheet. I am relatively new to Python and I am sure there is a much better way of doing this, I just don't know how.

```
def update_table(sort_column, value, change_column, change):
    df = pd.read_excel("PumpsLiterature.xlsx")
    df.loc[df[sort_column].str.contains(value), change_column] = change
    df.to_excel("PumpsLiterature.xlsx")
```

Currently I have to call the function for every change I want to make and it is extremely slow.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
update_table('PartNum', 'A050-BAA-GTPN-S30', 'Spare Parts File', 'a050-metal-iom.pdf')
update_table('PartNum', 'A050-BAA-SSPE-S30', 'Spare Parts File', 'a050-metal-iom.pdf')
update_table('PartNum', 'A050-BAA-GTPN-S30', 'Manual File', 'a050-metal-iom.pdf')
update_table('PartNum', 'A050-BAA-SSPE-S30', 'Manual File', 'a050-metal-iom.pdf')
update_table('PartNum', 'A050-BAA-GTPN-S30', 'Data Sheet File', 'a050-metal-iom.pdf')
update_table('PartNum', 'A050-BAA-SSPE-S30', 'Data Sheet File', 'a050-metal-iom.pdf')
```

Comment: Well the read and write parts take a lot of time. When you call your `update_table` multiple times you reopen and rewrite the xl. You should only do both actions once

Comment: Another good habit is to profile slow code to see what is the bottleneck, something like [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) works though there are other libraries as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file *once*, make all the changes you want, then write the file *once*.

You can do that by making a list of the desired changes, and then iterating over that list:

```
changes = [
    ['PartNum', 'A050-BAA-GTPN-S30', 'Spare Parts File', 'a050-metal-iom.pdf'],
    ['PartNum', 'A050-BAA-SSPE-S30', 'Spare Parts File', 'a050-metal-iom.pdf'],
    ['PartNum', 'A050-BAA-GTPN-S30', 'Manual File', 'a050-metal-iom.pdf'],
    ['PartNum', 'A050-BAA-SSPE-S30', 'Manual File', 'a050-metal-iom.pdf'],
    ['PartNum', 'A050-BAA-GTPN-S30', 'Data Sheet File', 'a050-metal-iom.pdf'],
    ['PartNum', 'A050-BAA-SSPE-S30', 'Data Sheet File', 'a050-metal-iom.pdf'],
]

df = pd.read_excel("PumpsLiterature.xlsx")

for ch in changes:
    sort_column = ch[0]
    value = ch[1]
    change_column = ch[2]
    change = ch[3]
    df.loc[df[sort_column].str.contains(value), change_column] = change

df.to_excel("PumpsLiterature.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it not only with one file read, but also with one search, which can be quicker at least in parts where you perform one search, but change different columns' values.

```
file_name = 'PumpsLiterature.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_name)

df.loc[
    df['PartNum'].str.contains('A050-BAA-GTPN-S30|A050-BAA-SSPE-S30'),
    ['Spare Parts File', 'Manual File', 'Data Sheet File']
] = 'a050-metal-iom.pdf'

df.to_excel(file_name)
```

---

For mock dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'PartNum': ['xxxA050-BAA-GTPN-S30', 'yyyA050-BAA-GTPN-S31', 'zzzA050-BAA-GTPN-S30', 
                'cccA050-BAA-SSPE-S30', 'aaaA050-BAA-SSPE-S31', 'bbbA050-BAA-SSPE-S30'],
    'Spare Parts File': ['value'] * 6,
    'Manual File': ['value'] * 6,
    'Data Sheet File': ['value'] * 6
})
print(df)
```

that looks like

```
                PartNum Spare Parts File Manual File Data Sheet File
0  xxxA050-BAA-GTPN-S30            value       value           value
1  yyyA050-BAA-GTPN-S31            value       value           value
2  zzzA050-BAA-GTPN-S30            value       value           value
3  cccA050-BAA-SSPE-S30            value       value           value
4  aaaA050-BAA-SSPE-S31            value       value           value
5  bbbA050-BAA-SSPE-S30            value       value           value
```

result will look like this

```
                PartNum    Spare Parts File         Manual File  \
0  xxxA050-BAA-GTPN-S30  a050-metal-iom.pdf  a050-metal-iom.pdf   
1  yyyA050-BAA-GTPN-S31               value               value   
2  zzzA050-BAA-GTPN-S30  a050-metal-iom.pdf  a050-metal-iom.pdf   
3  cccA050-BAA-SSPE-S30  a050-metal-iom.pdf  a050-metal-iom.pdf   
4  aaaA050-BAA-SSPE-S31               value               value   
5  bbbA050-BAA-SSPE-S30  a050-metal-iom.pdf  a050-metal-iom.pdf   

      Data Sheet File  
0  a050-metal-iom.pdf  
1               value  
2  a050-metal-iom.pdf  
3  a050-metal-iom.pdf  
4               value  
5  a050-metal-iom.pdf
```